# Scrollview in 'present modally' view controller not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a view controller that is to be presented modally and in that VC I have a scrollview. However, adding a scrollview normally does not seem to work when my segue is of type 'present modally'. I read somewhere that I have to put my scrollview in another view for it to work. So this is my view hierarchy:

[image]

These are my constraints for view A:
[image]

ScrollView constraints:
[image]

ViewB constraints:
[image]

And in ViewB, I have another view which I have given a top, left & right constraint of 0 to its superview. I have set this in code as well:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    viewB.frame.size.height = 2000
    scrollView.contentSize = viewB.frame.size
}
```

However, the scrollview still does not scroll. Thanks to anyone who can help out...been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have given ViewB constraints to its containing scroll view. This is fine, if you're going to take that approach (which I prefer); but it means that the scroll view's `contentSize` is determined by ViewB's size, not by the `contentSize` property. Thus, your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` code is useless and your first move should be to throw it away.

Now then, what *is* ViewB's size? Unfortunately, it's the same as the scroll view's size, because you have given ViewB width and height constraints that made it the same size as the scroll view. Therefore there is nothing to scroll.

The solution is to do through constraints what you were trying to do in code, namely, give ViewB a height constraint that is fixed at 2000, instead of height constraint you have given it.

Comment: By the way, the fact that your screen shot shows the red arrow-in-a-circle means your constraints are bad. You need to fix that before you do anything else. To proceed with bad constraints is pointless, as you cannot possibly get a meaningful interface at runtime. Also, I can tell you right now, looking at your screenshot, that you have a very bad habit of overdetermining your constraints, and that is going to get you in serious trouble.

Comment: First off thanks for the help Matt. And you are right, I do have a habit of overdetermining my constraints. Tho I always happen to have an error because of the scrollview. My scrollview has a non-fixed height, so what I normally do is pin the scrollView to the top,left,right,bottom. But then xCode throws an error that I need to specify the width and height of the view in the scrollview. And the height is non-fixed, so I set it in code. Is it a better approach to do it completely in code / completely in storyboard?

Comment: As I said in my answer, I like doing it through constraints in the storyboard as you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by non fixed , but the whole advantage of constraints here is the instead of a fixed height constraint you can have ViewB's subviews use their constraints to size the content from the inside out.

Comment: If I don't give viewB a height constraint though, xcode shows an error. Is there a way I can set a height constraint that isn't fixed? ie. 2000

Comment: No. :) Keep a reference to the constraint and change it again later in code as needed, or do what I said before: give it no height constraint, but give its _subviews_ sufficient constraints to size it from the inside out. Either way, if you don't have the final contents at nib-making time, you will ultimately have to manipulate constraints, in code, to set the height.

Comment: Look in particular at cases 2 and 3 in this example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p363scrollViewInCode3/ch20p670scrollViewInCode3/ViewController.swift